# consumer-producer pattern in Android, some advice to improve performance?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, producer-consumer

On Android I have a normal Consumer - Producer scenario:

1. Different producer thread can add object to the list in
   different time
2. When a certain event (Trigger event) appens a
   consumer start to keep element from the list (there is only one
   thread consumer.
3. When the list is empty the consumer it stop to
   keep element from the list
4. As soon as the list is not empty the
   consumer must tale the element from the list
5. The consumer must
   be fast to keep data, as soon as the element it inserted in the list
   from the producer the consumer have to keep it
6. I have this
   scenario in a singleton, and I have to stop thread only when the app
   is shutdown.

*

7. ***One of the producer is sometimes the UI thread***

*
What type of synchronization and list do you suggest to use ? I would do this without waste cpu load.

I'm scared of point 7.. i don't want to block for a lot of time the UI thread

***EDIT :*** for add details for @Alex

I'm writing it in pseudocode:

```
Thread C producer : calls EventTracker.trackEvent( C )
UI producer : calls EventTracker.trackEvent( A )

EventTracker
{
    BlockingQueue<Event> blockingQueue
    trackEvent(Event x)
    {
        blockingQueue.offer(500, ms);
    }

    Thread consumer
    {
        while(true){
            Event p = blockingQueue.poll(100, ms);
        }
    }
}
```

if the timeout is triggered on trackEvent(A) the UI producer not waiting for long time but Does the event "A" missed ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try [SEDA approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_event-driven_architecture) to this problem with queuing and using an implementation like [Blocking queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

in your case, the producer insert event in the queue by using 'offer' and the consumer take them by using 'poll'. (use the Timeout on those method to exit nicely the producer/consumer when the user quit the application)

note that there is a few things to get right on the Threading side when using this approach.

here's an [example of the concept](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) from the android developer documentation.

Comment: Hi @Alex ! Thanks for your time :) I have to study seda approach, however I'm so scared if producer has to wait Long time on blocking queue (because ui thread is One on them) and I can't miss any event . In what Way do you suggest me To use timeout on offer And Poll queue To exit nicely  when The user quit the app?

Comment: hi @aeroxr1, don't be scared, when the timeout expire the obect is null, so you can implement as much behavior as you want, the goal is that the timer is around 100 milliseconds up to 500 milliseconds depending on your producer and the way you want the user experience be.

Comment: but if the timeout is too short I loose some event , in the other hand if the timeout is too long I risk to lock for long time the ui producer or any other producer.
Furthermore I don't understand in what way can I understand when the user quit the application, to be sure that I can quit the thread

(and I have to study english -.-")

Comment: that's not the meaning of this pattern, if the timeout runout, that just mean that the queue was empty, if you loop and you retry, the you'll catch the next event in the queue. for the producer, the offer blocks only if the queue is full (so ensure at least some capacity to it ....) meaning that if you consume sufficently fast the queue should never be "full". you should really read attentively the wikipedia post about SEDA and how producer/consumer works (involving reading about threading and event loop).

Comment: thanks ! You are crystal clear :)
I add some pseudoCode in my first post. 
However I have thought that the timeout is triggered also if the blocking queue lock is retained for long time by the consumer, but actually should not happen . 
However in which way can I handle the end of thread consumer when the app is closed by the user ?

Comment: hawww so cute... let's just say the answer lie in the "exit" button or condition of your application and if the code that is handling the "exit event" of your application is aware of the Consumer and Producer queue, it can either : "pass the blue pill" to the Queue, killing the Consumer or just call a function to signal to the consumer to quit nicely. all is in the code of how you process your event loop in the consumer and producer. so if you just loop in the consumer queue without doing any sanity check like 'must i exit ?' or 'must i do something out of ordinary ?'.

Comment: The consumer timeout is a little problem.. I think I have to set timeout only on producer because I will have an active loop on producer if the list is empty to a long time. I have to study a consumer that is less heavy for cpu ..

Comment: if you do that and doesn't communicate the end of the application by passing an "event" to the consumer, the thread will have no way to exit as it'll be locked by the "get" on the queue.

Comment: Exit button for the app will not be sufficient since the user can just go to the home screen or hit the back button.  You'll want to use lifecycle events such as `onStop` or `onDestroy`.

Comment: @nasch that's also why you don't want to block the Thread, so it can check by itself if it must terminate.